# Reading values from a Flutter TextField

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a widget with a TextField that I'm initializing from a `StreamBuilder`, trying to use the bloc pattern. A Contact model is coming in through the stream. This is working to initially populate the TextField. My question is about reading the value after the user updates the TextField and then presses the Save button. How do I read the value from the TextField. I've included a simple example of what I'm trying to do.

```dart
  void getTextValues() {
    //???
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<Contact>(
      stream: bloc.getContact,
      builder: (context, contact) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: TextEditingController(text: contact.data.name),
            ),
            new RaisedButton(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.blue,
              onPressed: getTextValues,
              child: new Text("Save"),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

I think I could declare a TextEditingController and assign that to the controller property but I don't see a way to give that an initial value from the StreamBuilder. Am I missing something there?

```dart
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();

  ....

  controller: nameController,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think I could declare a TextEditingController and assign that to the
>   controller property but I don't see a way to give that an initial
>   value from the StreamBuilder.

There is a way. Change your builder code to this:

```
builder: (context, contact) {
    nameController.value = TextEditingValue(text: contact.data.name);
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: nameController,
            ),
            new RaisedButton(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.blue,
              onPressed: getTextValues,
              child: new Text("Save"),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
```

Comment: Ah! So simple! I don't know why it didn't occur to me I could put code above the return. Thanks @Ryosuke

Comment: happens to even the best of us :)

Answer (score 0):

To assign `TextEditingController` a default value, use

```
TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController(text: "Default value");
```

And to retrieve the value from a controller you can use

```
_controller.value
```